# How can images be resized using Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a website about products. Each product article has text and some images in it. The images range from 400px width to some going up to 700px width. The product article is stored in a SQL Server database and the article is fetched dynamically based on the productid.

I am using Bootstrap to make my website mobile friendly. I have a two column layout. The product article is contained in a Div marked with a

```
 class="col-md-12 row"
```

When I shrink the size of the page to preview how it would look in a mobile device the text nicely adjusts itself, however the images don't. Now i have about 3000 such images and if there is an attribute that I have to apply to every individual image tag, that won't be feasible.

Is there any other way using CSS or bootstrap or javascript where I can reduce the size of the image for a device size, keeping the image aspect ratio intact ?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Just add this somewhere in your stylesheet and it will apply to all images on your site.

```
img {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

Comment: Tom that was spot on. Thank you for sharing your knowledge.

Comment: Works like a charm using bootstrap ver 5. Thank you Tom!

Comment: I'll just join. Thank you, Tom! xD

Answer (score 16):

Bootstrap v3 and below.

Use class="img-responsive" in the image tag. This will automatically adjust the size based on the screen size. Its a bootstrap class.

Ex: http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_img_responsive&stacked=h

Bootstrap v4

Use class="img-fluid" in the image tag. This will automatically adjust the size based on the screen size. Its a bootstrap class. see comment below for more details

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I mentioned in my post that I have 3000+ images. Adding this class individually to 3000 images will not be feasible.

Comment: You can add this attribute using javascript/jquery after DOM ready.

Comment: @user2024285 in that case just use a universal selector img { width: 100% } .

Comment: Bootstrap v4 renamed img-responsive to img-fluid.
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/migration/

Answer (score 4):

With a Specific Width:

```
<img src="assets/img/why1.png" style="max-width:20%;" alt="...">
```

Automatic Width:

```
<img src="assets/img/why2.png" class="img-fluid" alt="...">
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to this.

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-4">
    <img class="thumbnail img-responsive" src="h.jpg" />
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Bootstrap 3 ➜ 4 Migration, `img-responsive` has been renamed `img-fluid`. https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/migration/#images

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to css

```
.col-md-12 img {width:100%}
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
 #imgdiv { width:40vw;display:table-cell;vertical-align:middle; text-align:center;}
img {max-width:100%;height:auto;max-height:100%;}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div id="imgdiv" class="col-sm-5 text-center">
        <img class="thumbnail img-responsive"  src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/736230/pexels-photo-736230.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500" 
            style="maxwidth:100%;height: auto;max-height: 100%;"> 
 </div>
</div>
```